# Splash screen by using layer-list element for Android Pad and Phone device

Tags: android, xml, qt, layout

I am Android and iOS developer. I use Qt and QtCreator as my tool. I am trying to create a splash screen for the android device. The splash screen happen in my android/res/drawable/splashscreen.xml as below code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
 <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_img"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:tileMode="disabled"
   android:gravity="fill"
 />
</item>
<item>
<bitmap android:src="@drawable/logo"
 android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

There are some folders and images in my project as below path.

```
android/res/drawable/
android/res/drawable-hdpi/
android/res/drawable-ldpi/
android/res/drawable-mdpi/
android/res/drawable-xhdpi/
android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/
android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/
```

The problem is the splash-screen image of (HUAWEI)M3 8.4 inch and Xiaomi Redmi Note 4X 5.5 inch are both from  the folder "android/res/drawable-xhdpi/". And our "@drawable/logo" is almost fill_horizontal with the screen width. If I update the "@drawable/logo" and let the image size to fit our 5.5 inch device, then the logo will too small for the 8.4 inch device. If I update the "@drawable/logo" and let the image size to fit our 8.4 inch device, then the logo will been out of the screen for the 5.5 inch device.

What should I do?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_drawable" android:resource="@drawable/splashscreen"/>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.splash_screen_sticky" android:value="true"/>
```

splashscreentheme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: resize your image to fit different screen sizes and put it in the correct folder. here are the screen sizes -  `drawable-ldpi        //240x320
drawable-mdpi        //320x480
drawable-hdpi        //480x800
drawable-xhdpi       //720x1280
drawable-xxhdpi      //1080X1920
drawable-xxxhdpi     //1440X2560`

Comment: I had google some relative problem about the size as the [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes). But the logo looks too small in our 8.4 inch android device. Hence, I had try many possible method to keep the image ratio and relative position on our pad and phone device. However, I don't success. Hence, I use "center" to keep our logo shape but the size is wrong on the 8.4 inch device.

Comment: can you show what you have done in the layout file..?

Comment: I had updated my post and show my all xml code about the layout in the below.